# Can I implement horizontal scrolling on the overflow of a tbody when the tbody is set to its container's width?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve the following:

1. A `table` element inside a containing `div`
2. The `table` has no `width` set (could be 100%) but it needs to be no wider than the containing `div`
3. The `table`'s cells are fixed width (using `width` and/or `max`/`min` `width`)
4. The `width` of the `table` cells are wider than the width of the containing `div`
5. **The `tbody` element in the `table` needs to scroll horizontally**

Is this possible? In the code snippet below, you can see what I am trying to achieve. The width of the container is `200px`. And the `table` has 3 columns of `100px` each (for a total width of `300px`). You can see the background of the container is red, and is shorter than the `table` width. My goal is to have the `tbody`'s width stay at it's container's width (`200px`) and scroll the overflow horizontally.

However, I know that the `table` and `tbody` elements' default behavior has some rules that prevent that from happening. Is there a way to configure this so that the `tbody` will scroll the overflow horizontally, **without specifying a hard `width` in the `tbody` element**?

```css
.container-container {
  background-color:#ccffcc;
}
.container {
  background-color:#ffcccc;
  width: 200px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
tbody {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 29px;
  width:100%;
  overflow: auto;

}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <table id="callLogExplorer">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set `display:block` on `tbody`. Just place your overflow on the `<table>` parent, as Twitter Bootstrap does it. It works cross-browser/cross-device:

```css
.tableResponsive {
  background-color:#ffcccc;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 200px; /* or set max-width on it max-width: 100vw; */
}
#callLogExplorer {
  margin-top: 29px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  min-width: 100px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableResponsive">
    <table id="callLogExplorer">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for.